# Wrangling data from IMF, trying to produce an animated line plot for practice

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to set up a simple line plot that will reveal data by year with gganimate.

First problem is, my simple line plot shows a really weird range on the y axis.

Second problem, the animation won't work.  Error message reads:

> Error: along data must either be integer, numeric, POSIXct, Date,
>   difftime, orhms

In addition:

> Warning message: In min(cl[cl != 0]) : no non-missing arguments to
>   min; returning Inf"

```
ggplot(data = Japan_GDP3, 
       aes(x = Japan_GDP3$Year, y = Japan_GDP3$`Exports of Goods and Services, Nominal, Domestic Currency`,
           group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(Japan_GDP3$Year)
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Don't use `$` in `aes()`. 2. Check whether your y variable is actually numerical (looks like it's a factor). 3. If the above don't solve your problem, consider making your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by editing your question with the ouput from `dput(Japan_GDP3)`.

Comment: Thanks Z. Lin.  You were right, the variable was a character.  I imported the data into R with read_xlsx and all numbers were imported as characters.  Do you know how to change that?  I tried as.numeric but that didn't work

Comment: Hard to diagnose that without seeing your data...